# I need help extending wifi signal to six buildings

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Here's my situation: I'd like to extend wireless signal to a large area that encompasses 3 large buildings and 3 cabins.

From the router there are wires running to three access points. Two access points are inside large buildings, one on either side of the building. The third access point is outside the building, pretty much directly above the router.

There are three cabins approximately 75 meters away from the main building. I'd like to install extenders in the three cabins so I can have reliable wireless coverage in each.

Two cabins "see" the signal @ -70dbm while the third is @ -90dbm. I installed a test extender to the middle cabin which works perfect.

Can I install a second extender in the other cabins, feeding off the same AP? How would I  configure the  IP, SSID, channels, etc? At the end of all of that can I have everything running off SSID and one PASS?

I'm not sure what to do at the cabin with the weak signal.

Answer (score 2):

Signal repeaters use the same SSID, PASS and CHANNEL. each time the signal is repeated, the speed is reduced by half. 54mbit becomes 24 which becomes 12 and so on. it depends what extender you use, but most linksys can be configured with a laptop.